# How do I fix numpy ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras

Can anybody please assist with the below code error? I am prepping my data to train it with deep learning model, but could not complete this due to numpy ValueError.

This is my raw data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1skaoLARqjrEeLOf4R-9Ulh89M8KWOTYD/view?usp=sharing . After cleansing, this is the final output used for training my model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_OOkuSTQ7Y6iQJALbGUtJ5Fs10POuBY/view?usp=sharing .

Below is class `WordEmbedding` for training my model:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from matplotlib import pyplot
import string
import re
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from pickle import dump
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Embedding

class WordEmbedding:

    def __init__(self):
       print(" ")


    def load_dataset(self, filename):
       file = open(filename, 'rt')
       dataset = file.read()
       file.close()
       return dataset 

    def createSequence(self, tokens):
       length = 50 + 1
       sequences = list()
       for i in range(length, len(tokens)):
           seq = tokens[i-length:i]
           line = ''.join(seq)
           sequences.append(line)
       data = '\n'.join(sequences)
       return data


   def encode_words(self, dataset):
       data = dataset.split('\n')
       newShape = 2, -1
       tokenizer = Tokenizer()
       tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
       sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
       vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
       sequences = array(sequences)
       #sequences = np.array2string(sequences)
       sequences  = np.reshape(sequences, newShape)
       #sequences = np.array2string(sequences)
       print(sequences.dtype)
       print(sequences.shape)
       X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1]
       print(y.dtype)
       #y = np.array2string(y)
       y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
       seq_length = X.shape[1]
       return X, y, vocab_size, seq_length, tokenizer
```

The below code is used to test class `WordEmbedding` :

```
from WordEmbedding import WordEmbedding


emb = WordEmbedding()
data = emb.load_dataset('trecis2018-test.parisAttacks2015.txt')
seq_data = emb.createSequence(data)
X,y,vocab_size,seq_length,tokenizer = emb.encode_words(seq_data)
model = emb.define_model(vocab_size, seq_length)
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, epochs=100)
model.save('model.h5')
emb.dump(tokenizer, open('tokenizer.pkl', 'wb'))
print("successful")
```

The below is error message when the code is run:

```
Reloaded modules: WordEmbedding

object
(2, 104309)
object
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-18-9db02c6b1f06>", line 1, in <module>
 runfile('/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project/processor.py', wdir='/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project')

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/envs/researchProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
 execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/envs/researchProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
 exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project/processor.py", line 15, in <module>
 X,y,vocab_size,seq_length,tokenizer = emb.encode_words(seq_data)

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project/WordEmbedding.py", line 77, in encode_words
 y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/envs/researchProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.py", line 25, in to_categorical
 y = np.array(y, dtype='int')

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: if the shape of `sequences` is `(2, 104309)`, and `y = sequences[-1]`, then `y` is a scalar. Doesn't make much sense to me to put that in `np_utils.to_categorical`?

Comment: @MrFuppes, initially I had `X, y = sequences[:, :-1], sequences[:, -1]` , but this also threw same error. So I'm not sure why the error.

Comment: What does the array contain?  It's object dtype

Comment: @hpaulj, the array contain word tokens, sample is as follows:  ["restaurant", "paris", "district", "gunman", "held", "hostage"...]

Comment: Can you share **all** relevant code and data? Please see: [mcve], [ask].

Comment: @Alexander Cécile, I appreciate you wanting to help. I have edited the original post to include the data and relevant code as requested. Pls kindly let me know what your recommendations are.

Comment: That first snippet of code is a class?

Comment: Yes it is a class

Comment: @Alexander Cécile, I have updated the first snippet of code i.e class `WordEmbedding` to include more lines.

Comment: @user6747582 I think there’s an extra quote in your code. Take a look at the return statement in the `createSequence` method.

Comment: @Alexander Cécile, the quote in question (or any other seen in the code snippet) isn't present in the actual code in my IDE, these came about while trying to format the code on this platform. Apologies for confusion these may have caused.

Answer (score 0):

`return data` in the method: createSequence, and retry the flow, if it works.

Comment: `return data` doesn't work. However I have edited the code snippet, but still same error.